# Can perlbrew install or run in C shell

Tags: perlbrew

I've perl version 5.22.0 but I need to downgrade it to 5.12.4. is it possible in linux system ?

I found the perlbrew and install it in Red Hat 6 bash shell but I need to use it in c shell. Is it possible to run perlbrew in C shell ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to install 5.12.4 on your system (without or without `perlbrew`).

Yes, `perlbrew` is compatible with `csh`.

If you already have `perlbrew` installed, just add the following to your login script:

```
source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/cshrc
```